# Access 2003 -- show new record as committed upon OpenForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

The user needs to create a new order.  To allow this, we have a button that opens the order form to a blank record in the Order table:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmOrder", , , , acFormAdd
```

The form comes up and is ready to go.  But the new Order ID number displays `(New)`.  That field is an autonumber.  When I make an entry anywhere on the form, `(New)` is replaced by the ID number.  But I want it right away.

I figure it's because the new record is not committed.  Can I make an initial commit so the primary key is displayed upon opening?

I tried using `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` to force a commit in the `Form_Load()` event, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This might be a bad idea,

if you commit first, how can you cancel the order, without modifying your db ?

By default, even if frmOrder is opened for acFormAdd, if the user click on the button [Close], AutoNumber is not modified. If modifying any field on the form either by VBA or by a user trigger, AutoNumber is incremented by 1, even no record is inserted at the end, or even cancelled.

#### Anyway, there is a method, assuming

```
Me.txtOrderDate.Controlsource = "OrderDate"
```

then

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Me.txtOrderDate.Value = Now()

End Sub
```

If you have an OrderDate field, or like, ID is automatically generated by Access.

Be careful, if you use SQL Sever Backend, ID is not assigned until the record is committed.

Comment: @Smandoli This is good advice. If your form is linked to an Access table then you don't need to commit the new record for the AutoNumber value to appear, you just need to make the form dirty. I also wouldn't be surprised if someone questions *why* the user needs to see the AutoNumber value at all, let alone the instant the "add new" form opens.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, yes, the base of the method is to make frmOrder dirty.

Comment: In this particular case, cancelling the order is not a concern -- but I appreciate the point.  As for Gord Thompson's comment, we all know creating a record "on the fly" can be problematic, and the desire for an immediate capture of the generated key is pretty common.  But again, the principles you both assert are straightforward and I appreciate your insights.